# URL rewriting with jquery (function load)

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have problem with url rewriting  and cell page by jquery function load

i use url rewriting by .htaccess for example :

```
http://localhost?id=1&article=5 => http://localhost/page/1/ or http://localhost/page/1/5/
```

and code jquery`$("#pg").load("../test.php");`

this code jquery not work  if i use `/page/1/5/`  only with `/page/1/`
(i have add ../ or remove if use /1/ or /1/5)

i went method for cell page test with all url `/page/1/5/  or /page/1/`

thank you

Comment: please , provide you rewriting code

Answer (score 0):

In cases where the path folder depth can be dynamic, such as this, you should base all URLs from the root folder, not the current folder. Try this:

```
$("#pg").load("/test.php");
```

Comment: Well this was just an example. You need to amend the actual URL to fit your path structure.